# asset_path helper is not implemented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, activeadmin, sprockets

I am receiving this error when trying to compile assets on Heroku

```
   Custom asset_path helper is not implemented
   Extend your environment context with a custom method.
   environment.context_class.class_eval do
     def asset_path(path, options = {})
     end
   end
```

I have tried pretty much everything I could find through google. Heroku seems to be getting caught up when precompiling the assets active_admin.css, which contains 2 @import statements. If I comment those out, the build proceeds, but without the active admin stylesheets working in production.

If anyone has any thoughts, please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing all config in application.rb relating to asset precompiling, and added a catch all compile script. I guess somehow it was missing a file, which caused the error:

```
# Precompile all assets
# application.rb
config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |path|
  if path =~ /\.(css|js)\z/
    full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
    app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
    if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
      puts "including asset: " + full_path
      true
    else
      puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
      false
    end
  else
    false
  end
end
```